# IntelliJ IDEA: How to quickly open a DB table editor?

Tags: database, intellij-idea

Scenario: I'm in IntelliJ IDEA DB console and looking at

```
SELECT * FROM TableXY;
```

I want to see the definition of the TableXY. One way of doing it is:

- ctrl+click on the table name: Looks up the table in the Database window.
- F4: Opens the table editor.
- select the `Text` tab

The problem is that I'm on a DB with a lot of tables and the first step takes forever because IDEA loads the full list of tables.

Is there a way to jump to the table editor directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but to quickly view the table definition you can use the *Quick Documentation* pop-up:

Place your cursor within the table name and hit CTRL+Q (or F1 on Mac). This will show you some information about the table, the first rows, and the table definition (output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`).

You can also configure the Quick Documentation under Settings > Tools > Database (see [Intellij IDEA on-line help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/database.html?search=database%20quick%20documentation#quick_doc)).

Comment: This is actually even better than what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!